# Ionic 3 Proxy not working after build and deployed to Server

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Ionic and currently using ionic 3 for making progressive mobile app. I was using ionic proxy on my local environment to avoid CORS issue which was working perfectly but when I build it using **ionic build** command and deployed it on my server, proxy seems to be not working. 
Can anybody please help me out.
Thanks alot in advance.

ionic.config.json file :

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/",
      "proxyUrl": "https://example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

ionic info :

```
    @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.5.8
    @ionic/cli-utils        : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.11.3
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: same issue on my side, too.

    @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.5.8
    @ionic/cli-utils        : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node  : v9.10.1
    npm   : 5.6.0 
    OS    : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145 

Have you found solution for this issue?

Comment: @rener172846 I have asked the same question on ionic forum check the answer- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-3-proxy-not-working-when-deployed-on-server/125670

Comment: I have understood what's the purpose of Ionic proxy. That's for only developing ionic project far away from API.
But after web build version, you should change the API as local.
This is the ionic notes for proxy:

_Note: Don’t forget to change the URLs being requested in your app to the local URL. Also, the “livereload” command must be restarted for the proxy configuration to take effect._